# What is difference between "setComponent" and "setClassName" in sending an intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, explicit-intent

From my own Android app, I'm trying to launch an **external app**'s component **explicitly**.

```
Intent i = new Intent();
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://0.0.0.1");
i.setData(uri);
i.setComponent(new ComponentName("other.app.android","other.app.android.Activity1"));
startActivity(i);
```

Can I replace `i.setComponent(...)` to `i.setClassName("other.app.android", other.app.android.Activity1")`? 
Please let me know what is the difference between them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. Internally `setClassName(String, String)` creates a `new ComponentName(String, String)`

```
public Intent setClassName(String packageName, String className) {
    mComponent = new ComponentName(packageName, className);
    return this;
}
```